# How to use a crate only for a given platform?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to use the `nix` crate in a project.

However, this project also has an acceptable alternative implementation for OSX and Windows, where I would like to use a different crate.

What is the current way of expressing that I only want `nix` in Linux platforms?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's two steps you need to make a dependency completely target-specific.

First, you need to specify this in your `Cargo.toml`, like so:

```ini
[target.'cfg(target_os = "linux")'.dependencies]
nix = "0.5"
```

This will make Cargo only include the dependency when that configuration is active. However, this means that on non-Linux OS, you'll get a compile error for every spot you use `nix` in your code. To remedy this, annotate those usages with a `cfg` attribute, like so:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
use nix::foo;
```

Of course that has rippling effects as now other code using those items fails to compile as the import, function, module or whatever doesn't exist on non-Linux. One common way to deal with that is to put all usages of `nix` into one function and use a no-op function on all other OSes. For example:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
fn do_stuff() {
    nix::do_something();
}

#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
fn do_stuff() {}

fn main() {
    do_stuff();
}
```

With this, on all platforms, the function `do_stuff` exists and can be called. Of course, you have to decide for yourself what the function should do on non Linux.

Comment: But how about cargo? Should I just add dependencies for different platforms there without any annotation?

Comment: Is it possible to put this annotation directly in the `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: I've updated my answer - I think without the target being specified in `Cargo.toml`, Cargo would still try to compile `nix` on other platforms!

Comment: If you want a good example of this in practice - [`rand`](https://github.com/rust-random/rand) has a dependency on `winapi` that only applies when built on Windows.